# How to resolve db:migrate error SQLite3::SQLException: no such table:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to use the social network gem inkwell.
I am following the simple instructions [here](https://github.com/salkar/inkwell) .

I have created a Post, User, Category and Community model using rails generate model 
I then configure the models and run

```
$ rake inkwell:install:migrations
$ rake db:migrate
```

but end up with the error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: posts:
```

There is a migrate file for this model and I always thought that once you'd created the model then following a migrate it would create a table so I'm a bit confused. Certainly when I `rails console Post.all` there is no table so this migration isn't happening.

Comment: You have to create user and post model,run the new migration,then follow the instructions.

Comment: please add as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is said in the instructions you have to create before the model for users and posts.
So if we assume you have just created the models with a generator, run the migrations for them:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Creating so the required tables and then:

```
$ rake inkwell:install:migrations
$ rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a `rake db:reset`? 
Or delete the database file and:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```